# Cronjob to Run PHP File and Post Output to Text File (Overwriting Previous File) Every Minute

Tags: php, ubuntu, ssh, cron

Good morning,

I am looking for the correct formatting for the above cronjob to put in my crontab.

At the moment, I have this:

`* * * * * php /var/www/html/Vatsim/online.php > /var/www/html/Vatsim/online.txt`

However, this is just removing the contents of the text file and not replacing it with the new output from the php file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need a way to set cron job in ubuntu or something other you talking about ?

Comment: I know where to set the cronjob. I'm just not sure of the correct formatting for the cronjob to achieve what I want it to.

Comment: Do you get what you want when you run the command by hand on the command line.

Comment: Yeah. When I run the command from the command line it works. I just run online.php > online.txt from the VATSIM folder.

Comment: Try the full command "php /var/www/html/Vatsim/online.php > /var/www/html/Vatsim/online.txt" from your home folder. Maybe there is a typo or something. Also try to give the full path to php. If you don't know where PHP is located use the command "whereis php".

Comment: I fixed it. Set the full path of the vendor file in the php file and then the cronjob worked. Thanks!